# Laravel storage returns FileNotFoundException But file exists

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filesystem, laravel-6.2

I want read file content in laravel 6, the file already exists but laravel return not found exception.

This is my logs files directory:
`/var/www/html/myLaravelLab/storage/logs/laravel-2019-10-14.log`

```php
$contents = Storage::get(storage_path('logs/laravel-2019-10-14.log'));
```

Laravel return this error: `Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\FileNotFoundException`

But file already exists!

I want read file contents.

---

Laravel Version: 6.2.0
- PHP Version: 7.2.19

Comment: Can you `dd(storage_path('logs/laravel-2019-10-14.log'))` to see the actual path? Otherwise might be permission issue?

Comment: I do and see this result: "/var/www/html/myLaravelLab/storage/logs/laravel-2019-10-14.log"

I give permission 777 to all folders and files ...

But still see that error!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `config/filesystems.php` add new disk `logs`:

```php
'disks' => [
        'logs' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('logs'),
        ],
// orher disks...
```

Now you can get log files:

```php
Storage::disk('logs')->get('laravel-2019-10-14.log');
```

Answer (score 0):

`storage_path('logs/laravel-2019-10-14.log')` will return the full path to the resource, such as:
 `http://www.app-name.com/storage/logs/laravel-2019-10-14.log`.

Storage::get() accepts a path **relative to the storage disk's root**.

You likely need to not include `storage_path` in your function, and try something like:

```
Storage::get('logs/laravel-2019-10-14.log')
```

See where the disk is searching for the file, then adjust the path until you are searching the correct directory.

Comment: I do that but still return error! 

Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\FileNotFoundException

Answer (score 0):

storage_path will essentially prefix the path you give it with the path to the storage folder, so `/var/www/website.com/storage/logs/laravel-2019-10-14.log`.

If you use Storage::path() this works similarly, but from the configured storage disk (so this can be cloud based if you like). The main difference is this looks in `storage/app` instead, so you will need to move your logs in there, or possibly you might be able to say:

```
$contents = Storage::get('../logs/laravel-2019-10-14.log');
```

or

```
$contents = file_get_contents(storage_path('logs/laravel-2019-10-14.log'));
```

## Edit:

I've just checked and you can't use the `Storage::get('../')` as it goes out of the available scope. If you would like to use the `Storage::get()` method you will need to adjust the location in your config.
In `config/filesystems.php`

```php
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        // 'root' => storage_path('app'),
        'root' => storage_path(),
    ],
]
```

then you can use

```
$contents = Storage::get('logs/laravel-2019-10-14.log');
```

Comment: ```php
$contents = file_get_contents(storage_path('logs/laravel-2019-10-14.log'));
```
Work Fine...

Comment: Such a change can lead to breakdowns in other places of the application. It is better to create a new separate disk.

Comment: This is true! If it's not a completely new app it would be better to create a new disk. (Probably best to create a new one either way)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the Storage class is overkill for your implementation. You could just use the PHP file_get_contents() function instead:

```
$contents=file_get_contents( storage_path( 'logs/laravel-2019-10-14.log' ) );
```